# Spree deface override tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I am following the Spree deface overrides developer guide: http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/deface_overrides_tutorial.html

My code matches their's exactly, but I keep getting this error. I looked all around but I didn't see anyone else having this problem or anything similar at all:

undefined method `content_tag' for Spree:Module

I am running Rails 4.0.2 and ruby 1.9.3 (it's possible that the tutorial wasn't updated for rails 4?)

here's my code:

app/overrides/add_sale_price_to_product_edit.rb

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => 'spree/admin/products/_form',
  :name => 'add_sale_price_to_product_edit',
  :insert_after => "erb[loud]:contains('text_field :price')",
  :text => "
    <%= f.field_container :sale_price do %>
      <%= f.label :sale_price, raw(Spree.t(:sale_price)) %><span>*</span>
      <%= f.text_field :sale_price, :value =>
        number_to_currency(@product.sale_price, :unit => '') %>
      <%= f.error_message_on :sale_price %>
    <% end %>
   ")
```

app/models/spree/product_decorator.rb

```
module Spree
  Product.class_eval do
    delegate_belongs_to :master, :sale_price
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting the error because the translation for Spree.t(:sale_price) is not specified.  This is failing because Rails 4.0.2 made some [changes to the I18n API](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/78790e4bceedc632cb40f9597792d7e27234138a) .  You have a few choices.

1. Add a translation for the missing tag and remember that this content_tag issue is caused by this crazy bug.
2. Downgrade to Rails 4.0.0 (not recommended)
3. Upgrade spree to the 2-1-stable branch (or wait until 2.1.4 is released)
4. Apply [this change](https://github.com/spree/spree/commit/cb5abb8914403bc26797114d23b07d3fe81fa210) to your local Spree installation.  It should correct this issue.

Any of those should get you working again.